# Solr Lucene - disable ordering by date and time the document was indexed?

Tags: date, solr, lucene, indexing

Please could I ask for some help in the order my search results are returned? It seems to me that when a document is re-indexed, it appears at the end of the search results.

I'm ordering by 'score desc' only, so I don't know how items that are re-indexed are ending up as the last results.

Is this date-of-index ordering something I can turn off or control in any way?

Many thanks indeed for your help - its hugely appreciated.
Seb.

Comment: There is no date/time involved in scoring unless you are boosting your results according to the document added date. So even if the document is added the last the document if relevant should appear on the top.

Comment: Understood - but why when I re-index something why does it fall to the bottom of the search results? It shouldn't have any bearing on the order of my results.

Comment: What do you mean by re-index? Are you updating documents providing the same id?

Comment: Higher scores should come first regardless of the time any document was indexed.  The only case where the time would have effect is when all the scores being returned are equal.  Are you getting a range of scores back or all the same value?

Comment: Sorry, to clear things up, when I say re-index, I mean updating the document with the same ID.

Comment: what the scores for the documents ? are they different can you check the debug information ? is anything in the query causing it to be a constant score response ??

Answer (score 0):

for sorting ignoring date/time you can use [Random Sort](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html), then it will return results ignoring date/time thing that you have mentioned